# accessing the json return variable

Tags: asp.net, json

I have an ajax call handled with jquery like this:

```
var GetAppointmentDate = "{'DateInput' : '02/02/2011'}";

$(function () {

    $("#mydiv").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../Pages/Appointments.aspx/GetAppointements",
            data: GetAppointmentDate,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFn,
            error: errorFn
        });
    });
});
```

I've been debuggging the code behind to the point where I know the returned data is what I want: the page method end with "return result;" and the variable result contains the json strong I need. Now how do I access the data returned in the front-end.

So far I have:

```
function successFn(){
    alert(msg.d);
};
```

Nothing's being outputted. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your success function to accept a parameter and then you can refer to the returned data.
i.e:

```
function successFn(msg){
    alert(msg.d);
};
```

Comment: ok, this worked. Now the problem is that in the return string I have some dates that are formatted like this: "AppointmentTime":"\/Date(1296625740000)\/" Do I need to do some sort of processing to convert the date, or even the whole returned variable, into json that's properly formatted?

Comment: Can you get the JSon without wrapping the numeric value in Date()? And is the numeric value Milliseconds?

Comment: I don't understand? The native type of the property is a date; what do you recommend I do?

Comment: In the sample JSON you have posted, can you get the value of AppointmentTime as "AppointmentTime":"1296625740000"?